# How to politely decline a job because of the following reasons

Tags: recruitment, hiring-process, software-development

I've got an interview invitation from one of the places that I've always wanted to work in.

Thing is, I'm a student, and I sent my resume 2 months ago before my semester started. Since I didn't hear from the company until the semester started, I decided eventually to take 6 courses which makes my semester very busy and doesn't leave any time for a job right now.

How do I decline this job politely and keep the opportunity to work there, maybe next semester (or even in 2 semesters which is approximately 8 months)?

English is not my native language, so I would really appreciate help with the choice of the wording.

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser Im located in israel, but the company is international so all the formal  emails and communication with job applicants is in english, so I'd really appreciate some help with wording formally my reasons do decline the job right now, but keep the opportunity for the next 4 months (or maybe 8, 1-2 semesters).

Comment: "from one of the places that I've always wanted to work in". Maybe you should look at changing your courses instead of declining to interview? (But only after a successful interview).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cancel job interview without burning any bridges?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/126274/how-to-cancel-job-interview-without-burning-any-bridges)

Comment: @GregoryCurrie It is not possible right now because we are in the middle of the semester. Also, my grades are more important for me than a student role right now.

Comment: @gnat Not really, I asked for helped with wording my specific reasons which are a lot different from the reasons explained in the post that you gave. Also, I would like to apply to this job in the close future, which is different from the question in the other post.

Comment: Are you applying for a specific job, or is this more of a "we're always looking for interns/students" kind of opening?

Comment: @Erik I suppose that it is the second option, although for a specific role as an engineer student in specific field

Comment: So basically, what you want is tell them you would be interested at a later time, because your current agenda is already filled for the semester. You could possibly explain that during the interview.

Comment: @Clockwork Wouldnt going to the interview although I know Im not ready to start the job yet, be considered as a waste of their time? Also one can only apply for this company once a few months (I think half a year) , so I would not want to waste this chance

Comment: Hmm... I was thinking about taking the opportunity to make a good impression, and to let them know that even though you are not immediately available, you intend to approach them again later on when you are. Still, I'm still quite new to the professional world, so these are mostly hypothesis from stuffs I heard and read.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the culture in which I evolved might be different too, since I never worked in Israel.

Comment: Isn’t the semester only 2 months from ending?  Hiring cycles can often take that long.  I would go to the interview, when it comes up explain “I’m not available till end of the semester,” then at best you get a job at worst you get experience interviewing and negotiating with a company.

Comment: Keep in mind that business situations change rapidly. You can't even be sure that the company will be hiring in a few months. (There are companies that have gone under in that short of time.) Thus, politely state that your situation has changed and would love to talk to them in a few months but expect to start over from scratch in your job search.

Comment: Have they reached out to you for a part-time internship? for a full-time job? Or for a temporary summer internship? What have they told you? What is written on their website?

Answer (score 6):

> How do I decline this job politely and keep the opportunity to work there, maybe next semester (or even in 2 semesters which is approximately 8 months)?

Do not decline anything! Respond to them and state the date of your availability after this first semester is over. That's it.

And if you're willing to work there next semester, do not mention that you'd be willing to work there two semesters from now, or they're going to assume that next semester is not a good time for you, but that you're just not assertive enough to speak your mind.

And building on the previous message written by Ertai87, this is what I'd write.

> Hi (recruiter's name),
>
> Thank you for reaching out. I'm very excited about this opportunity.
>
> Unfortunately, I can now only start on (insert date here).
>
> Would that date still work for your company? Since I had not heard back from my initial application two months ago, I'm afraid I've already taken on a full course load since then.
>
> If my availability works for you, I'm available for a phone screen on (insert days and times). My number is 555-555-5555
>
> Thank you,

Of course, this message is assuming that you're applying to some kind of part-time internship program. If you're applying for a different type of job, or if I'm missing some crucial piece of information, this message may need to be changed accordingly.

Comment: I feel like most companies would respond to this email with "We don't know what our hiring needs will be like that far in the future, so we'll have to decline your candidacy at the present time".  I think the ask of postponing the entire recruitment discussion would be more productive than only the start date.

Comment: @Ertai87, You may be correct, but why try to assume what's on their mind when you could just state your position and let them decide for themselves. Even if the recruiter says "Let's wait then" and then places the email in her tickle folder, then that's the desired outcome by the OP. Isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

> Hi John/Jane (recruiter's name)!  Thanks a lot for reaching out to me, and I'm super excited for the invitation to interview with you.  Unfortunately, I have a bit of a situation right now which is going to make it difficult to accept the interview.  I'm a student, and I'm currently in school; when I applied I was between semesters so I would have been able to take some time off for work, but my semester has now started and I'm focusing on my studies.  However, I'm really happy that you replied and I would love to explore an opportunity when I have another break in my study schedule; could I contact you again directly, rather than applying through your portal, when I'm available and pick up the interview then?

I'd send exactly that.  Most recruiters, especially from big companies, will reply to you and say "absolutely, feel free to email me directly in the future and best of luck on your studies".